# JQuery: $.ajax calls seem to be blocking image download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have a series of AJAX calls that are fired to the web server to load more information after the DOM is loaded (I wrap the calls in the $.ready function). However, it still seems to be blocking. I did not set the async option in my code. Am I doing something wrong here? Below are my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var places = #{@results.to_json};

    Places.SERP.initialize(places);
  });
```

In my serp.js where the Places.SERP.initialize(places) is defined:

```
  initialize = function(places) {
    initMap(places);
    initDeals(places);
    initFriends(places);
  };
```

In the 3 init* calls, I have numerous $.ajax calls to fetch more information from the server. The code looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  timeout: 1000,
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(retval) {
    if (retval) {
      var data = retval.data;
      if (data) {
        var stats = data.stats,
            friends = data.friends;

        if (stats) {
          $("#places-" + internalId).find(".checkins-wrapper").
            hide().
            append(template({
              checkinCount: stats.checkinsCount
            })).
            fadeIn();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
  }
});
```

Comment: isn't `url` point to  another domain ? Where are images which not loaded ?

Comment: url is pointing to the same server "/". the images are hosted on the same server (in the Rails public folder). It's weird that ONLY certain photos do not get loaded. It's really strange.

Comment: Browsers limit the number of consecutive http requests that can happen at once. I'm guessing that since both the images and the ajax targets are on the same domain, you are reaching that limit. Consider consolidating your ajax requests into larger requests rather than more numerous requests.

Comment: FYI: If @KevinBs comment is appliable you can put your images in a subdomain like pictures.mysite.com to get some more downloads at once.